# Get the checked radio button

Tags: java, android

I want to create dynamic RadioGroup (with dynamic radio options). I'm doing with the following code.

My question is that, how can I get the option that is selected by clicking the button "**Check Answer**". If the radio group is added through the XML layout then I can get by its ID, but in this case I'm unable to do so.

Here's the code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button">
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        android:textColor="#008b00"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check Answer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:onClick="checkAnswer"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.quiz8;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout linearLayout = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
        RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
        RadioButton radioButton;

        final String[] title = {"Male", "Female", "Other", "Secret"};

        for (int i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
            radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
            radioButton.setId(i);
            radioButton.setText(title[i]);
            radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
        }

        linearLayout.addView(radioGroup);
    }

    public void checkAnswer(View view) {
        //get the answer here
        TextView answerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
        answerText.setText("You selected the option...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a *tag*  to the `RadioGroup` in order to be able to find it easily. A *tag* can be any `Object`. We'll use a `String` here, which has to be unique in the `ViewGroup` on which you call `findViewWithTag()`. Then in `checkAnswer()` you retrieve the `RadioGroup` by its *tag* and so get the text of the checked `RadioButton`.

```
private static final String RADIOGROUP_TAG = "radiogroup";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
    radioGroup.setTag(RADIOGROUP_TAG);

    RadioButton radioButton;

    final String[] title = {"Male", "Female", "Other", "Secret"};

    for (int i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
        radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
        radioButton.setId(i);
        radioButton.setText(title[i]);
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
    }

    linearLayout.addView(radioGroup);
}

public void checkAnswer(View view) {
    //get the answer here
    RadioGroup radioGroup = linearLayout.findViewWithTag(RADIOGROUP_TAG);
    int checkedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton radioButton = radioGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
    String text = radioButton.getText().toString();

    TextView answerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    answerText.setText("You selected the option..." + text);
}
```

---

Another option: you can have `String[] title` and the `RadioGroup` as fields in your `Activity`. This makes sense since you need them in more than one place.

```
private final String[] title  = {"Male", "Female", "Other", "Secret"};
private RadioGroup radioGroup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
    radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);

    RadioButton radioButton;

    for (int i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
        radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
        radioButton.setId(i);
        radioButton.setText(title[i]);
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
    }

    linearLayout.addView(radioGroup);
}

public void checkAnswer(View view) {
    //get the answer here
    int checkedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    TextView answerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    // Note: make sure there is a checked RadioButton! 
    answerText.setText("You selected the option..." + title[checkedId]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check for the selected one.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout linearLayout = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
        RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
        RadioButton radioButton;

        final String[] title = {"Male", "Female", "Other", "Secret"};

        for (int i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
            radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
            radioButton.setId(i);
            radioButton.setText(title[i]);
            radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                //checkedId is the RadioButton selected
            }

        }

        linearLayout.addView(radioGroup);
    }

    public void checkAnswer(View view) {
        //get the answer here
        TextView answerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
        answerText.setText("You selected the option...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to get the checked answer by clicking the Check answer button (ie. in the **checkAnswer** function)?

Comment: Yes you can. just declare an int and assign it's value in tthe "onCheckedChanged" method. for example int i = 0;  -> i = checkedId; and then in the "checkAnswer query that int. This will get you the current id that was selected. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

1) You can add following code in `OnClickListner()` to check if desired check boxed is clicked.

```
// Is the button now checked?
boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

// Check which radio button was clicked
switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.radio_pirates:
        if (checked)
            // Pirates are the best
        break;
    case R.id.radio_ninjas:
        if (checked)
            // Ninjas rule
        break;
}
```

Further help can be found in Radio button documentation : [Radio Button Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton)

2) Another method: A better way is to use `RadioGroup` and set the listener on this to change and update the View accordingly (saves you having 2 or 3 or 4 etc listeners).

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
    }
});
```